# angular cli 6 Failed to load external scss files in the style.scss ? node_modules/raw-loader/node_modules/postcss-loader/lib??embedded

Tags: angular, sass, angular-cli-v6

> ERROR in ./src/styles.scss
>   (./node_modules/raw-loader!./node_modules/postcss-loader/lib??embedded!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--14-3!./src/styles.scss)
>   (Emitted value instead of an instance of Error) CssSyntaxError:
>   /Users/src/assets/sass/modules/partials/_landing.scss:5:16:
>   Can't resolve '../assests/images/header-bg.png' in
>   '/Users/src'
>
> 3 | }   4 | .inner-page-banner {
>
> > 5 |     background: url(../assests/images/header-bg.png) no-repeat center;
> >         |                ^   6 |     background-size: cover;   7 |     /* background-attachment: fixed; */
>
> ℹ ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.

Angular.json

```
"build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/Yosso-buyer",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },



"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.6.8",
    "@angular/cli": "~6.0.8",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/language-service": "^6.0.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.6",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "~4.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "^2.0.4",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.3.0",
    "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "~2.7.2"



"@angular/animations": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/common": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/core": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/http": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/router": "^6.0.3",
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.1",
    "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.14.3",
    "rxjs": "^6.0.0",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uVcf6.png)

Comment: Have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/q/42351593/7124761

Comment: here, i don't have webpack.config.json file. i generated the application using angular cli version 6. (issue with node-sass loader)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the path is wrong from the error: `assests`

```
'../assests/images/header-bg.png' in '/Users/src'
```

but under assets you have

```
"src/assets"
```